# Android studio value increment in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

Can anyone teach me how to update my Firebase value when I click on my Android Studio App? There is no need to retrieve and display the data. Just an incremental value in my Realtime Database. For example, the Firebase counter value is 0 now, how I can increase the counter value in Firebase when I click on a button? I have tried using the code below, but it is not working.

```
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;

public class Voting extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button msendData;
int counter;
    private  Firebase mRef;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_voting);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        mRef = new Firebase("https://lollol.firebaseio.com/");
        msendData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.votethis);
        msendData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Firebase mRefChild = mRef.child("Booth A");
                mRefChild.setValue(counter++);
            }
```

Comment: This looks like it should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: 20222608

Actually, there is a really simple solution nowadays in which we can increment a field in the Realtime Database which is:

```
scoreRef.setValue(ServerValue.increment(1));
```

And to decrement a value, simply pass a negative number:

```
scoreRef.setValue(ServerValue.increment(-1));
```

---

In order to increment a value in a Firebase database, first of all, you need to retrieve that value. There is no way to increment a value without knowing it. To achieve this, I definitely recommend you to use [Firebase Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

Let's take an example. Let's assume we want to increment a counter. In order to achieve this, please use the following code to set the default value of the counter.

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.child("score").setValue(1);
```

Assuming that the `score` field is of type Integer, to use transactions, please use the following method:

```
public static void setScore(String operation) {
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference scoreRef = rootRef.child("score");
    scoreRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            Integer score = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
            if (score == null) {
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            if (operation.equals("increaseScore")) {
                mutableData.setValue(score + 1);
            } else if (operation.equals("decreaseScore")){
                mutableData.setValue(score - 1);
            }

            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
    });
}
```

Using `transactions`, you will avoid inconsistent results if users are trying to increase/decrease the score at the same time. So as a conclusion, call this method accordingly to your increase/decrease operation.

If you want to read the score, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference scoreRef = rootRef.child("score");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Integer score = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
        Log.d("TAG", "score: " + score);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
scoreRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: how do i store the value in variable?

Comment: currently i did it this way but got got error  mRef = new Firebase("https://lollol.firebaseio.com/Booth A");
        mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           int value= dataSnapshot.getValue(int.class);
                int counter=value;
            }

Comment: Please always use transactions to update a counter like this. Without those, this is a race condition waiting to happen.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen You're right Frank. It was a very old answer, just edited accordingly. Hope you reconsider my answer :) Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the update Alex. I was surprised because I think I saw a very similar answer from you that *did* compare load-and-set vs a transaction (which is a server-side compare-and-swap).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Oh ya. I'm constantly improving my answers as soon as I find one old and inappropriate but I missed this one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries. When you answer a lot (as you do) that's a constant struggle. I actually just found that [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414073/allow-read-in-firestore-rules-based-on-timestamp-value-in-document) may now be possible, but I need to find a moment to test it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That's right. I saw your edited post. I tried to use `allow read: if request.time < resource.data.timeCreated + duration.value(3, 'm');` to allow a read if the file was created less than three minutes ago but it didn't work for me. I'll run a few more tests. Thanks!

Comment: The `setScore` function has a return even thought its void, but how do I detect if its successful or not!?

Comment: @Learn2Code No, `doTransaction` function has a return statement since the return type is `Transaction.Result`. If you have anoher question which is not related with this one, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: @alex, actually I walked away from using your proposed solution. The `doTransaction` does not work for me. When executing with two or more devices and the counter needs to increment it actually gets into an endless loop.  I created a custom solution using recursion that checks the counter value in firebase and based on that it increments the counter if allowed (due to firebase rules).

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the value from the database.
2. Make a simple while loop, with the number of increments you need. Declare the variable globally, not within the onCreate methods.
3. Set them back to the Database.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to retrieve the value if you use ServerValue.increment(). Recently, It landed on Flutter in version firebase_database 4.1.

The way you can use is:

```
mRefChild.set(ServerValue.increment(1));
```